# Problems with systemupdate

Tags: update-manager

I currently have Ubuntu 13.10 installed, but the problem also came up when I had 13.04.

The update via GUI doesn't work! It tends to crash every time I want to do an update.

If I do it from the terminal with `sudo apt-get update` everything works just fine, but as the computer is for someone with much less knowledge about those things it has to do the update the normal way!

It is no problem with my internet, because another computer with Ubuntu does the same updates just the way it's supposed to be!

If you have anny suggestions how to fix that or need some more information, feel free to leave me a comment or answer.

Comment: Can you try running the update manager from the commandline and see if it gives you any errors?

Comment: To run the Software Updater / Update Manager from the command line, the command is simply `update-manager`. It will probably still crash or otherwise fail to work, but assuming that happens, there may be valuable messages written to the terminal. So if anything at all appears in the terminal, you should select the complete output, copy it to the clipboard, and add it to your question (by editing). Also, you might try `gksudo update-manager` in case the problem is related to the way the Software Updater uses polkit. If this is closed you edit it, it'll be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that the connection/configuration from your system to the software update server is not properly set. My recommendation is to enter System Tools -> Software Update -> Configuration -> Ubuntu Software (tab) -> Download from: -> (then choose a different server, I got mine set to Spain Server but another choice/option I have is to set it to Main Server). So you'd have to change your setting to a different server. Once the change is made you'll have to type your password in order for the change to take effect. Then close the window.